# build gps tracker for nokia devices

Tags: gps, nokia

i need to build a very simple application for nokia devices ,

the application without ui - or with it's not a big deal -  when user opens the app ,

the app starts to send the coordinates via http connection , the application must work in back ground   , my question here is :

what is the best development kit for this simple app , QT ?! native Symbian ?! cross platform (html , js) ?!

thanks ,